# Trouble with certain websites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

so I'm working on 2 projects and having issues accessing the websites. The first one is my blog [website](https://www.craftyhangouts.com/), the second one is a fandom wiki which I edit (https://horizon.fandom.com/wiki/Horizon_Wiki). When I'm trying to upload the page, all I see is a white screen. I turned off the extensions, reloaded the router, and even PC - not helping.

The problem appeared when I installed a new router (Xiaomi 4A). I did it in the morning and had no time to check everything during the day, and now I have so many things to fix, but I can't access my blog!

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Susan

Comment: Did you try flushing your browser cache?